# Automatically replacing specific value in a .conf with preset

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, debian

I'm actually using a Wireguard configuration and I would like to automatically change the server with a script before loading it.

Here's the idea: Each server has a unique public key and port, script would change the publickey and endpoint line to a random server (using its publickey & port).

Here's how a Wireguard configuration look like

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [HIDDEN]
Address = [HIDDEN]
DNS = 2.2.2.2
[Peer]
PublicKey = [PUBLIC KEY]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 1.1.1.1:[PORT]
```

What I want to do here is to replace the port at the end of the endpoint and replace the publickey. The IP (1.1.1.1) does not change at all.

After a few research, it seem I need to use `sed` but I don't know how to put all of this in place since I also need some preset values for the other servers.

Here's an example:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = QajJg8GJPQwCD743EXD8TmKlA1wQAqz9mSBqclPg2zw=
Address = 10.65.31.104/32,fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::2:1f67/128
DNS = 193.138.218.74

[Peer]
PublicKey = 4ZoyMZqQ8k94bQ3egN2vOyiSPG9nZ611r1606wtmVQI=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 217.138.200.226:3099
```

Final result should replace Endpoint port (3099) and Publickey (4Zoy...mVQI=) to a random other server coming from a preset list
Let's say script choose randomly publickey "JdSt...6CHk=" and port 3088 (for server ca5) it should look like this

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = QajJg8GJPQwCD743EXD8TmKlA1wQAqz9mSBqclPg2zw=
Address = 10.65.31.104/32,fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::2:1f67/128
DNS = 193.138.218.74

[Peer]
PublicKey = JdSt7WR/eeiHeGdj3W5XrTDrkyv4EdM3+3P/Jkg6CHk=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 217.138.200.226:3088
```

I would like some help to guide me in the good direction. Thanks you !

Comment: Please add representative sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus Updated with example. I hope it's what you were waiting for.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

This will do the trick.

```
# Let's assume the existing config file is called wireguard.cfg
#

# Let's first save the IP , because we will need it later again
#
OLD_IP=`grep Endpoint wireguard.cfg| cut -d= -f2|cut -d: -f1`

# Assuming that we know the NEW PUBLIC KEY and NEW PORT
NEW_PUB_KEY="foobar1234zdhakjdhaj"
NEW_PORT="1234"

# Now we will replace the Public Key and the Port
# New file will get spit out on standard out
# You can always use > to send it to any new file 
sed  "s/.*PublicKey.*/PublicKey = $NEW_PUB_KEY/" wireguard.cfg | sed  "s/.*Endpoint.*/Endpoint = $OLD_IP:$NEW_PORT/"
```

Here is an example run:

```
mamuns-mac:~ xmrashid$ cat wireguard.cfg 
[Interface]
PrivateKey = QajJg8GJPQwCD743EXD8TmKlA1wQAqz9mSBqclPg2zw=
Address = 10.65.31.104/32,fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::2:1f67/128
DNS = 193.138.218.74

[Peer]
PublicKey = 4ZoyMZqQ8k94bQ3egN2vOyiSPG9nZ611r1606wtmVQI=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 217.138.200.226:3099
mamuns-mac:~ xmrashid$ 
mamuns-mac:~ xmrashid$ ./modify_wireguard.sh 
[Interface]
PrivateKey = QajJg8GJPQwCD743EXD8TmKlA1wQAqz9mSBqclPg2zw=
Address = 10.65.31.104/32,fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::2:1f67/128
DNS = 193.138.218.74

[Peer]
PublicKey = foobar1234zdhakjdhaj
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint =  217.138.200.226:1234
```